# How to put chrome extension under the task context?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

[image]

My extension is `BBox Counter`, i want to put `BBox Counter` under the task context like AdGuard AdBlocker.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "BBox Counter",
    "version": "2.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {

            "match_about_blank": true,
            "all_frames": true,
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "BBox Counter"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "contextMenus",
      "storage",
      "identity"
    ],
    "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    }
}
```

I want to do so because i am getting `Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null` this error while executing `document.getElementById(element_id).getElementsByTagName("rect").length;` code using `BBox Counter` extension but when i am execute this code in console if the javaScritp context is in top then it's shows same error message but when i am set it to task then it's execute successfully.

Please help me with that. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding `"run_at": "document_start"`.

Comment: @wOxxOm please help me with that

Comment: I have add `"run_at": "document_start` but still not woring