# How to add 'Read and change all your data on the websites you visit' permission in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, extension-methods

I need to add `Read and change all your data on the websites you visit` this permission in my chrome extension so that i can read the `DOM` elements of the page.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "BBox Counter",
    "version": "2.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "match_about_blank": true,
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "16.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "BBox Counter"
    },
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "contextMenus",
      "storage"
    ],
    "content_security_policy":"script-src 'self' https://www.gstatic.com/ https://*.firebaseio.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    }
}
```

**Update**
**content.js**

```
console.log("context started...");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("Message received");
    const element_id = "event-capturer";

    if (message == 'count') {
        if (document.getElementById(element_id)) {
            const cnt = document.getElementById(element_id).getElementsByTagName("rect").length;
            alert("Count is: "+cnt);
        } else {
            alert("No element with '"+element_id+"' tag.");
        }
    }
}
```

that site has a `div` with id `event-capturer` but i don't know why it's going to else part `"No element with '"+element_id+"' tag."`.

please help me with that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you are doing the right way.

when you inject content scripts like what you are doing now, you are getting the correct permission.

```
   "content_scripts": [
        {
            "match_about_blank": true,
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ]
```

this means you inject `content.js` to every webpage. try write some code like `alert("I'm here")` in the content.js, and reload the extension, then open any page you will get an alert.

how to check the permission status?

- right-click on the extension icon in the toolbar
- hover on `this can read and change site date`
- if it selected the `on all sites` by default, then it can access all sites.

Comment: by adding `"tabCapture"` in `permission` i got the permission to `read the site content` but no luck

Comment: @Arup what do you mean `read the site content` no luck, `tabCapture` is for taking tab screenshot.

Comment: @Arup if you want to read the page content. just try write something like `alert(document.title)` in your content scripts. you will see it will alert the page title.

Comment: I mean after adding `tabCapture` it show `has access to this site` in my extension.

Comment: And @Hank X can you please go to this question this is my main problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61608815/how-to-put-chrome-extension-under-the-task-context